# How to extract specific information from CDATA section of an xml file with VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

My question is similar to what is described [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1502303.aspx?How%20to%20extract%20specific%20information%20from%20CDATA%20section%20of%20an%20xml%20file%20). However it is not for Excel-VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that actually the text property resolves away the CDATA escape characters of `<![CDATA[]]>`.  So actually code is quite simple.  Here is an example.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sXml As String
    sXml = "<Root><SomeData>foo</SomeData>" & _
        "<SomeCDATA><![CDATA[<img src=""http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif""/>]]>" & _
        "</SomeCDATA></Root>"
    'Tools->References->Microsoft Xml v.60
    Dim dom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set dom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    dom.LoadXML sXml
    Debug.Assert dom.parseError = 0

    Dim xmlSomeCData As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Set xmlSomeCData = dom.SelectSingleNode("Root/SomeCDATA")

    Debug.Print xmlSomeCData.Text

    '* or your suggestion :)
    Dim xmlSomeCDataSection As MSXML2.IXMLDOMCDATASection
    Set xmlSomeCDataSection = dom.SelectSingleNode("Root/SomeCDATA/text()")

    Debug.Print xmlSomeCDataSection.Text

End Sub
```

the above code outputs `<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif"/>`

Comment: What does ´´'Tools->References->Microsoft Xml v.60´´ do?

Comment: It is just a comment that says you need to add a Tools Reference to the Mirosoft Xml library.  Otherwise the code will not compile.  So in the IDE, goto the top menu bar, take Tools then from the submenu take References then from the dialog box that pops up scroll down until you findf Microsoft Xml v6.0 and then check the checkbox next to it.

Comment: I got a compile error: User-defined type not defined. (after addint that comment.)

Comment: Have you gone to Tools->References dialog yet? because it will not compile until you follow the above comment/instruction.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I misunderstood. What does the line Debug.Assert dom.parseError = 0 do? My code is stopped here.

Comment: Also, for "Root/SomeCDATA", do I need text() at the end?

Comment: Debug.Assert will stop if the condition to the right is False.  The condition parseError=0 means the Xml was well-formed and the code successfully parsed the document and the remaining code will execute successfully.  On my computer this line runs through.  That it does not work on your computer means you have either not correctly copied over the text or you have amended/broken it.

Comment: Your suggestion works also, I have added lines to code implementing the extra `text()` you suggest.  Good one.

Comment: Thanks. I need to load the xml from a file. Is this correct :  dom.Load (XMLFileName)  (It does not work.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151387/discussion-between-s-meaden-and-aqqqq).